# sql server express lan

Tags: sql-server, permissions, configuration

I want to know if sql server (express) need to have always admin right on a computer.

I ask my company to have a version on my pc, but I need a tech to install it because I dont have admin right.

I'm afraid that I will not be able to use it after the installation.

I will need of course to manage it

and connect local

and connect remote lan

did you think my right will cause problem

(I know taht I can talk to a mysql db on my computer by lan)

I found this http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/install-and-configure-sql-server-2008-express and its said that I will need to enable TCP/IP, is it that I can do it? did I need it on lan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account which runs the SQL Server instance doesn't need admin rights on the computer and neither does the account which will manage the SQL Server instance.  If you plan on creating databases within the instance you'll need to make sure that you have sysadmin rights within the instance but this isn't related to the OS rights at all.  The person doing the install will need to make sure that they give you the rights within the database instance that you need before they leave.

The person doing the install that has admin rights will need to enable TCP/IP on the instance as that does require admin rights to do.

Comment: what do you mean by database instance, just like adding an db administrator user with all right?

Comment: When you install SQL Server you install an instance of the database engine.  Within the instance you create databases.  Within the databases you create tables which hold data.  To do everything possible you need to be an admin within the database instance.

Comment: yeah, but there probably user like root with all privileges (full admin)? If I get that, I will not need any more os admin right?

Comment: Yes there is the "sa" account which has full rights.  It doesn't matter if you use the "sa" account or if your Windows account has full rights into the SQL Server. In either case you don't need more rights in Windows.

Comment: So .... when my tech will come, He will install sql server, add a sa user and give the user/pass. After he need to enable TCP/IP and I will be good to use my db the way I want. thats right?

 new question: did I need to check witch port tcp use?

Comment: Yes you should be able to use the database the way you want to (as best as I can tell).  If he installs SQL Server as the default instance (no instance name) then it'll be port 1433 by default.  If he installs it as a named instance just make sure that the SQL Browser is enabled and running before he leaves and you'll be fine.

Comment: what do you mean by sql browser?

Comment: The SQL Browser is a Windows service that is installed by the SQL Server installed.  It is used with named instances as a part of the connection process.